# Scheme: vector function that returns the first odd number

Tags: racket

I can't figure out on how to write a vector function that returns the first odd number in the list.

Ex: (check-expect (first-oddnumb 2 3 4 5 6) 3)) ;;it returns 3 because 3 is the first odd number in the list.

Comment: vector function? Where are there any vectors here?

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out on how to write a vector function that returns the first odd number in the list.

My confusion is the same as @Sylwester's: "vector function"? The rest of the question seems to make sense tho.

I can help you write a function that returns the first odd number in the *list*.

---

We want the function to work like this

```scm
(first-odd-number 2 3 4 5 6) ;; => 3
```

So the first thing we have to do is learn how to write a function that accepts a variable number of arguments

```scm
(define (variadic . xs) xs)

(variadic 1 2)     ;; => '(1 2)
(variadic 1 2 3)   ;; => '(1 2 3)
(variadic 1 2 3 4) ;; => '(1 2 3 4)
(variadic)         ;; => '()
```

Note the `.` before the `xs` parameter. This gives us a way to collect all of the passed arguments into the bound identifier, `xs`. Notice how the arguments are collected into a *list*. Also pay attention to how `xs` will still be a list (empty list `'()`) even if no arguments are given in the function call.

Now we can begin writing your function

```scm
(define (first-odd-number . xs)
  ;; so we know xs will be a list here ...
  )
```

Let's talk about the possible states of `xs`

- `xs` could be empty, in which case what should we return? maybe a `0` or something? (more on this later)

Otherwise, `xs` has at least one number ...

- is the first number an odd number? if so, return that number
- is the first number an even number? if so, return `first-odd-number` of the remaining numbers in `xs`

OK, we can pretty much define this in Racket verbatim

```scm
(define (first-odd-number . xs)
  ;; begin case analysis of xs
  (cond
    ;; is the list of numbers empty? return 0
    [(empty? xs) 0]
    ;; the list is not empty, continue ...
    ;; is the first number odd?
    [(odd? (car xs)) (car xs)]
    ;; otherwise...
    ;; the number even, check remaining numbers
    [else (apply first-odd-number (cdr xs))]))

(first-odd-number 2 3 4 5 6) ;; => 3
(first-odd-number 3 4 5 6)   ;; => 3
(first-odd-number 4 5 6)     ;; => 5
(first-odd-number)           ;; => 0
```

And that's pretty much it !

---

**Improvements...**

If you're like me tho, that `0` is making you feel uneasy. What if you were given a list of only *even* numbers? What should the return value be?

```scm
(first-odd-number 2 4 6) ;; => 0
```

This is kind of weird. We could use the `0` to mean that no odd number was found, but *Maybe* there's a better way ...

```scm
(struct Just (value) #:transparent)
(struct None () #:transparent)

(define (first-odd-number . xs)
  (cond
    ;; no odd number was found; return None
    [(empty? xs) (None)]
    ;; an odd number was found, return (Just n)
    [(odd? (car xs)) (Just (car xs))]
    ;; otherwise check the remaining numbers
    [else (apply first-odd-number (cdr xs))]))

(first-odd-number 2 3 4 5 6) ;; => (Just 3)
(first-odd-number 3 4 5 6)   ;; => (Just 3)
(first-odd-number 4 5 6)     ;; => (Just 5)
(first-odd-number)           ;; => (None)
```

Now when the caller of our `first-odd-number` is working with the function, we don't have to don't have to remember that `0` is a special case we need to consider

```scm
(define (print-the-first-odd-number . xs)
  (match (apply first-odd-number xs)
    [(Just x) (printf "the number is ~a\n" x)]
    [(None) (printf "no odd number was found\n")]))

(print-the-first-odd-number 2 3 4 5 6) ;; the number is 3
(print-the-first-odd-number 2 4 6)     ;; no odd number was found
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a [comprehension](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html) to iterate over the vector (or whatever), specifically, [`for/first`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffirst%29%29), which returns the value returned by the first body that gets evaluated, combined with a `#:when` clause to limit said evaluation to the first odd element of a vector:

```lisp
#lang racket/base

(define (first-odd-number container)
  (for/first ([num container]
              #:when (odd? num))
    num))

(displayln (first-odd-number #(2 3 4 5 6))) ; 3, passing a vector
(displayln (first-odd-number '(2 3 4 5 6))) ; 3, passing a list
```

If no odd number is present, it returns `#f`.

While you get better performance by using type specific sequence builders like [`in-vector`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._in-vector%29%29) with a `for` loop, using a container directly like this gives more flexibility (It would also work with sets of numbers and a few other standard types)

If instead wanting a function that takes a variable number of arguments, use a hardcoded `in-list` and the appropriate formals:

```lisp
(define (first-odd-number . numbers)
  (for/first ([num (in-list numbers)]
              #:when (odd? num))
    num))
```